# Is it possible to view an array as label in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson

I tried to make a GeoJSON file where some properties have arrays:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              4654842.272603876,
              5135720.4450117
            ],
            ...
            [
              4653796.093490953,
              5124881.326846274
            ],
            [
              4653793.42338882,
              5124889.5345974155
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": 72757,
        "parent_id": 69911,
        "common_id": "61",
        "common_name": "81-61",
        "has_children": false,
        "shape_type_id": 4,
        "shape_type_name": "Precinct",
        "value": [
          "54.46",
          "29.34",
          "9.15",
          "4.93",
          "0.47"
        ],
        "color": null,
        "title_location": "Precinct: 81-61",
        "indicator_name_abbrv": [
          "Margvelashvili (Georgian Dream)",
          "Bakradze (UNM)",
          "Burjanadze (United Geo)",
          "Targamadze (CDM)",
          "Liluashvili (Init Grp)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I try to use them as labels they don't show up :

[image]

So, is it possible to view arrays as labels in QGIS ?

Comment: QGIS expects a string input for the label. An array is not a string. Use the `array` functions to convert your array into a string.

Comment: Sure, do you have any resources so I can learn how to do it? I'm pretty new to all of this

Comment: The best resource for the expression builder functions is actually the built-in help. To open the expression builder, click the epsilon button next next to where you chose the "indicator_name_abbrv" field in the label tab of the layer symbol panel. Click on any function in the list of functions, and the help panel will explain what that function does and give examples of how to use it.

Comment: You probably want the `array_to_string()` function.

Comment: @csk Thank you, the expression builder function has some indication to get started. It's another question but any chance you know how to transform a string to a float in QGis function editor unless there is already a function?

Comment: Conversion functions are under the "conversions" section of the expression builder. Use `to_real()` to convert a string to a decimal number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the array functions in the expression builder:

```
array_get("indicator_name_abbrv" ,1)
```

will use the second entry in your array.

[image]